# Shift Register 74HC595 not working

Tags: shift-register

I am trying to learn how to make a shift register work. I have been working off of the [Arduino ShiftOut tutorial](http://arduino.cc/en/tutorial/ShiftOut).

My issue is that the shift register isn't working when the circuit is powered and I am not sure what is wrong. I suspect the issue is with pins 10-13 on the 74HC595?

I have done this with an actual board and the 123d.circuits.io simulator with the same result:

http://123d.circuits.io/circuits/444111-shift-register

[image]

The code is very simple and taken from [the tutorial](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShftOut12):

```
// SH_CP; 11
const int clockPin = 9;
// DS; 15
const int dataPin = 8;
// ST_CP; 12
const int latchPin = 10;

void setup() {
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("reset");
}

void loop() {
  for (int number = 0; number < 256; number++) {
    Serial.println(number);
    digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
    shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, number);
    digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
    delay(500);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is GND (also) connected to Q0? Idem for STCP? You also need to swap the wires going to pins 11 and 12 on the chip.

Comment: @Gerben good catch that was a mistake.  see answer below for the other half of the fix

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Remove ground from Q0 as Gerben correctly pointed out in comments.

Also: rotate LEDs 90 degrees so that the anode and cathode are on different rows.

What was tripping me up is in the Arduino tutorial diagram is a little unclear on this (I now understand why their way is correct and my way (in the question) was wrong:

[image]

Comment: What software did you use to draw this breadboard schematic? It's really nice.

Comment: @IOBToolkitTeam https://123d.circuits.io/circuits/444111-shift-register